# Why fetchArray doesn't apply htmlspecialchars directly?

Tags: php, mysql, xss, sql-injection

To avoid SQL injection and XSS we use the function htmlspecialchars() or others like escapeString.

If we have to use this function every time that we construct a SQL query and get the results, why then the function

```
$results->fecthArray();
```

doesn't apply the function htmlspecialchars directly?

Comment: @Frank you're true, but I'm wondering in what cases I don't want it

Comment: When you're absolutely sure that the output you want shouldn't be escaped; e.g. you stored data that wasn't encoded in the first place. So, with Frank's comment, this falls under true.

Comment: One example would be if I want to store my javascript functions in a DB. I know, not very likely. A language like PHP by its nature will be open to many uses. A framework however, would probably implement its own fetchArray method that would apply htmlspecialchars.

Comment: See my comment below. htmlspecialchars is not always the correct escaping even when outputting to HTML.

Comment: cases: plain text email, text file output, formatted text from admin area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection attacks happen when there is a **change in the programming/instruction language**. Example, from PHP to SQL, you need `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape the query string before processing by the SQL server.

To answer your question, `$results` still remains as a PHP variable and you only need to do the escaping *just prior to* outputting on the HTML form. Most people don't do that straight away and some may not even output to HTML, so the function does not need to apply `htmlspecialchars` automatically.